# What default font does MS Word 2013 use to typeset formulas?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, latex

What default font does MS Word 2013 use to typeset formulas?

What would be the equivalent latex package to reproduce this font with latex (at least as close as possible)?

Answer (score 0):

#### What default font does MS Word 2013 use to typeset formulas?

It uses [Cambria Math](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=360).

> Out of the box, Office 2010 and 2013 have only Cambria with all of the
> math characters that are needed for the Equation Editor.
>
> You can verify this by clicking "expand link" at the bottom right of
> the "Tools"box in "Equation Editor" > "Design" tab:
>
> [image]
>
> After some considerable effort, I have still not found a compatible font so I have posted this with Microsoft Partner Support and after some back and forth, this is what they said:
>
> > "Cambria Math is the only supported font that can be used in Equation Editor in Word 2013 for the time being. Anyway, the DEFAULT FONT is a drop down box and it will have alternates after some improvements are made by the developing team."

Source [SOLVED: How To Change the Default Font in Equation Editor From Cambria](http://www.urtech.ca/2013/05/solved-how-to-change-the-default-font-in-equation-editor-from-cambria/)

---

#### What would be the equivalent latex package to reproduce this font with latex

You can use Cambria Math directly in LaTex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}

The Bezier curve $C$ of degree $m$ is
$$C(u) = \sum_{i=0}^m f_i(u)P_i$$

\end{document}
```

Source [Cambria Math becomes plain Cambria](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/cambria-math-becomes-plain-cambria)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Math Fonts in Microsoft Office](https://mrchasemath.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/math-fonts-in-microsoft-office/)